# NSView background image composed of 3 different files

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, image, nsview

I'm trying to set a background image of an NSView. (Actually an NSScrollView.) At the moment I'm subclassing drawRect: and I'm using `NSDrawThreePartImage` to draw the image but there are a few things that are not correct whenever I start scrolling.

[image: example image]

Are there better ways to draw the images?

```
- (void)drawRect: (NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    dirtyRect.size.height -= 18; //Moving the image up a bit for future subclassing of NSScroller.
    NSDrawThreePartImage(dirtyRect, viewLeftCap, viewFill, viewRightCap, NO, NSCompositeSourceOver, 1, YES);
}
```

Comment: `NSDrawThreePartImage` is usually the preferred way of doing this. You should probably post your `drawRect:` implementation.

Comment: Added. Not much there though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to redraw the whole view, you should be using [self bounds], not the rect passed into your -drawRect: method.

Comment: Specifically, Jane, the `dirtyRect` is just that: The rectangle that's dirty. “Dirty” means in need of updating; in this case, in need of redrawing. It is the section of your view's bounds that you need to redraw. You can draw more, but should not draw any less. (Drawing more than the dirty rect is discouraged for performance reasons, but it's otherwise harmless and sometimes unavoidable. I suggest clipping to the dirty rect when you have no other way to not draw outside it, as in this case.)

Comment: Thanks for the insight on this.